# how to make a post http request with Ngrx/Effects?

Tags: post, httprequest, ngrx-effects

how to make a post http request with Ngrx/Effects? 
i am working on a project where i should consume some services from a backend server, using angular and Ngrx /Effects, i made it with the get request but i'm struggling with post, can anyone help me with that !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are subscribing to your request, otherwise it wont work.

i.e.

```
httpClient.post('http://example.com/save', {name: 'Im posted'}).subscribe();
```

You don't necessary have to pass callback function into subscription, but if you want to do something as soon as your post is completed, then do the following:

```
httpClient.post('http://example.com/save', {name: 'Im posted'}).subscribe(() =>{
  console.log('Post request completed')
});
```

If that is not your problem, then please provide more details of your problem.